# @TopicNotOwnedByProject error while creating google classroom registration for topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console, google-classroom

I have two google cloud console projects. First one is for authentication purposes only and the second one is for work with classrom, it has topic, subscription, and classroom courses. I added user to both projects, on the second porject he is an owner, and for some reason i started to get errors while creating course registration to topic after authenticating on first project.

Full error is:

```json
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "@TopicNotOwnedByProject The specified Cloud Pub/Sub topic does not belong to your Developer Console project.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
```

When i do sign in in first project i use owner account for second project. So in request i pass token which got after signing in first project.
This errors started to appear about 3 weeks ago, did google change something or i am missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pub Sub Topic not associated with Project error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562731/pub-sub-topic-not-associated-with-project-error)

Comment: @ziganotschka thx, but i've seen it from the beginning, so nope it doesn't. For temp solution i moved topic and subscription under auth dev console project, but it's not the answer too.